# Failing to instantiate PlaceAutocomplete

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

I'm having issues with the google places autocomplete, I'm getting the following error and I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
2020-09-21 11:33:02.894 29037-29037/com.example.hostapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hostapp, PID: 29037
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
    Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete that is not a Fragment
```

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/places_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

and here is where im calling the AutoComplete in my code:

```
final PlaceAutocompleteFragment mUseraddress = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.places_autocomplete_fragment);
               //HIDE SEARCH ICON BEFORE FRAGMENT
               mUseraddress.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
               //set hint for address
               ((EditText)mUseraddress.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input))
                       .setHint("Delivery Address");
               //set font size for address
               ((EditText)mUseraddress.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_search_input))
                       .setTextSize(14);

               //GET ADDRESS
               mUseraddress.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                    deliveryAddress = place;
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onError(Status status) {
Log.e("ERROR",status.getStatusMessage());
                   }
               });
```

lastly, I have in my Gradle implemented.

//Google Services
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.2'

Comment: Shouldn't you use `android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment` in your XML? Source: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_1_embed_an_autocompletesupportfragment

Comment: ive tried it but i still get the same error.

Comment: when do you get the error exactly?

Comment: when i click the Autocomplete filed to type and address. the error has not changed, now it just says fragment not attached to a context.